# Angular form with dynamic clarity tabs get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError after add tab

Tags: angular, forms, tabs, vmware-clarity

I have reactive angular form with dynamic tabs. First - tabs with fields, then tab with button for add tab. If I add tab in form, I get error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'active: true'. Current value: 'active: false'.

It's clarity changed tab activated status, so I get this error. Tried use setTimeout - in delete tab it's working - have no error. But in adding - it's showed sometimes - offten when active tab not last. And sometimes I get activated addTab - but I change it to false manually.

```
onAdd(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  const info = this.listGroupDef();
  this.infoList.push(this.fb.group(info));
  this.infoList.markAsDirty();
  this.tabs.push(false);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.addTab = false;
    this.tabs[this.tabs.length - 1] = true;
  }, 0);
}
onDelete(event, index: number) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.tabs[index]) {
      this.tabs[0] = true;
    }
    this.tabs.slice(index, 1);
    this.infoList.removeAt(index);
    }, 0);
  event.stopPropagation();
  }

<clr-tabs>
  <clr-tab *ngFor="let InfoFormGroup of InfoList.controls; let infoIndex = index">
    <button clrTabLink>title<clr-icon shape="times" (click)="onDelete($event, infoIndex)"></clr-icon></button>
    <ng-template [(clrIfActive)]="tabs[infoIndex]">
      <clr-tab-content>
        angular reactive form
      </clr-tab-content>
    </ng-template>
  </clr-tab>
  <clr-tab>
    <button clrTabLink (click)="onAdd($event)"><clr-icon shape="plus-circle"></clr-icon></button>
    <ng-template [(clrIfActive)]="addTab">
      <clr-tab-content>
      </clr-tab-content>
    </ng-template>
  </clr-tab>
</clr-tabs>
```

Comment: My project using vmware-clarity ver 1.3.0. It will be difficult to use other lib.

Comment: If you can provide a stackblitz that has a working reproduction I would be happy to take a look at it. We keep starters here for several versions (Including v1 - just be sure to update the packages to the correct clr and angular  package versions) : https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-yc5f7c error appeared when add tab and then delete it and add again.

Comment: detectChanges helps - have no error, but I sometimes add tab becomes active. I guess - I have to make add button not as tab.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm still not clear on what the question is. What you are trying to accomplish here or what is the use case thats for it? It seems like you want to have a form in a tab and also be able to add new tabs with additional forms in it but thats just a guess. Thanks for the stackblitz, I played around with it a bit and modified it: removing all of the setTimeouts, change detection calls and e.stopPropgation(). But that doesn't yield an error in in my fork. But perhaps I misunderstood how the code should work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-cu71ng

Comment: Thanks! I should not use event.stopPropagation() for this task. I used it for forbidden changing tab when delete and add new tab. It's not working how I want it be.

Comment: My new version is https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-ufurth . Can't win with selected new tab - so I put add icon in last tab. Without event.stopPropagation() in the end activated was previous tab - not last. Can you tell - how I should change activate tab - all or set true the one I want (the last one)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide any additional information about your project ? There are three main reasons when this error appears:

1. You are executing code in AfterViewInit which often happens when working with ViewChild, as it is undefined until AfterViewInit is called.
2. You are manipulating the DOM directly (e.g. using jQuery). Angular cannot always detect these changes and react properly.
3. It can also happen due to race conditions when you are calling functions inside your HTML template.

Please follow these three rules and detect corresponding points in you app.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it all that there is the change happen which angular's change detector did not record.

Please read the following blog it explains the `ChangeDetectionStrategy`

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

In your code you could explicitly call the `detectChanges` method after your `active` property is changed.